# SignatureDoesNotMatch in aws s3 c# while getting presigned url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

Hi I have mvc application in which I want to get url of uploaded image in amazon s3 but after getting url its not able to get open in browser 
code to get Url is

```
  var expiryUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
        expiryUrlRequest.BucketName = BUCKET_NAME;
        expiryUrlRequest.Key = "uploads/participantid_" + v1+ "/taskid_" + v2 + "/" + 0 + ".mp4";
        expiryUrlRequest.ContentType = "Video/mp4";
        expiryUrlRequest.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);

     string    url = client.GetPreSignedURL(expiryUrlRequest);
```

I also get url but after pestling it into browser it show signature does not match.

Comment: Can you paste your code for GetPreSignedUrlRequest?

Comment: Its already amazon implemented method we just sending expiryUrlRequest object to that method  thats it.

Comment: What is the version of the SDK?

Comment: V3.1.6.2 for AWSSDDK.S3 And AWSSDK.CORE it is v3.1.6

Comment: If this is using Signature V4, pre-signed URLs have a maximum validity period of 7 days, though I would expect a different error.  And what purpose does `var data = expiryUrlRequest.Metadata;` serve?  And don't you need to specify somewhere that the method associated with the URL when you use it will be `GET`? (The request method is part of the canonical request, used when generating the signature).

Comment: sorry but I did not understand Canonical request.I am new in this area so I just want to get url.its working properly before some time now it give above error.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Specify the verb:
   expiryUrlRequest.Verb = HttpVerb.GET;
2. Check the bucket policy whether the IAM role / AWS account whose access keys you are using to access this bucket, is allowed access to the bucket (use tool: https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)
3. Use an expiry which is less than 7 days (won't help in solving this issue, but the maximum allowed value is 7 days)
4. Try ContentType as "video/mp4" (worth a shot).

Answer (score 0):

After Generating Presigned URL and binding to html. Signature with hex value is changing to asci symbols.

Make sure to create signature for presigned url without hex value